# Can't see write-host output in the log when running PowerShell in Azure in "Code + Test"

Tags: powershell, azure-functions

I have the simple script in run.ps1

```
 # Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Timer)
# Get the current universal time in the default string format.
$currentUTCtime = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()
# The 'IsPastDue' property is 'true' when the current function invocation is later than scheduled.
if ($Timer.IsPastDue) {
    Write-Host "PowerShell timer is running late!"
}
# Write an information log with the current time.
Write-host "PowerShell timer trigger function ran!"
Write-Debug "PowerShell timer trigger function ran! TIME: $currentUTCtime"
```

Why can I see ""PowerShell timer trigger function ran!" in the log on the bottom?

Comment: I think it has to be Write-Output and not Write-Host. Write-Host will display the output on screen during manual execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Dilly B, I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

Firstly, I have used `Write-Host`  and Ouput is displayed in Output Screen as below:

[image]

Then I have used `Write-Output` and got logs of it as below:

[image]

**Output in logs:**

[image]

**Edit:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the content of \host.json and the log level you use? I do not get what you show in green

Comment: @Ofer Gal, I have edited my answer with your requirements.

Comment: You get green in output screen if you use Write-Host and if you use Write-Output you will get in Logs.

Comment: Thanks @RithwikBojja I set my log level to INFORMATION and now Write-host adds information statements. I tried to make it green but it doesn't respect "-ForegroundColor Green" . But I can work now